# after execute makemigrations some items are missing in the result

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

The model name is Question, here is the code.

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True),
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    publishedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

After execute the command
`python manage.py makemigrations questions`

I've gotten The result

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Deal',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('publishedAt', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

I am wondering where is `title` and `subtitle`.

Comment: Have you notice a comma after your model fields? Remove it and run the command again

Comment: oh my mistake ... Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed commas after model fields, and gotten correct result.